# Create 2D array and store value into each element of that array in Scala

Tags: scala

I am working on a Scala exercise which asks me to create a 2D array of 4 rows and 5 columns and store the row index+column index+5 in each element. Also I have to sum the array by rows and then by columns and print the rows total and the columns total.I am so confused and I only know how to create an empty array.

```
val matrix = Array.ofDim[Int](4, 5)
```

Can you teach me how to do the rest of this exercise?

Answer (score 0):

I will not tell you "the rest of the exercise" but I will try to show one way to create a 2D collection, like an array in this case:

```
val matrix1D = for {
  rowIndex <- (0 until 4).toArray
  colIndex <- (0 until 5).toArray
} yield rowIndex + colIndex + 5
```

Where

```
scala> :t matrix1D
Array[Int]
```

Now the result of this for-comprehension is the 1D version of your 2D array.

**EDIT**

I could probably give you few more hints:

```
scala> (0 to 11).toArray.grouped(4).toArray
res10: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(0, 1, 2, 3), Array(4, 5, 6, 7), Array(8, 9, 10, 11))

scala> .transpose
res11: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(0, 4, 8), Array(1, 5, 9), Array(2, 6, 10), Array(3, 7, 11))
```

**EDIT**

After you create `matrix2D` from `matrix1D`:

```
val matrix2D = matrix1D.??????????????????
```

Where

```
scala> :t matrix2D
Array[Array[Int]]
```

To print it out, you could simply use `mkString`:

```
scala> matrix2D.map(_.mkString("\t")).mkString("\n")
res32: String =
5   6   7   8   9
6   7   8   9   10
7   8   9   10  11
8   9   10  11  12
```

Comment: @Flippo, `(0 to 11).toArray.grouped(4).toArray `is displaying this output `res0: Array[Array[Int]] = Array([I@6e7baf36, [I@5c7942fc, [I@2caed06a, [I@6272a544)` instead of what ur showing

Comment: @Aamir I am using `scala-2.11.4`:

Welcome to Scala version 2.11.4 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_72).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> (0 to 11).toArray.grouped(4).toArray
res0: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(0, 1, 2, 3), Array(4, 5, 6, 7), Array(8, 9, 10, 11))

Comment: @Flippo, I am using scala-2.11.7:Welcome to Scala version 2.11.7 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_45), so maybe version issue...